# Is there any field to hold an image in PDFBOX-1.8.10?

Tags: javascript, java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

In PDFBOX, I want to insert some images as form fields which can be stored in an acroform.
Later for some value changes in specific PDTextBox field by user, I want to invoke Javascript function to show/hide above image fields. Also confirm whether there is a support in javascript to make image field hide/show (i.e., If I am able to give name to such image filed then i think it is possible).

Is there functionality available in PDFBOX 1.8.10 to achieve this goal?
If yes, please provide reference code/document.

Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: I doubt that there is anything like that available in the examples. I think the best would be to create such a file with Adobe Acrobat (maybe a trial version), and then to reproduce all this with the methods available in PDFBox by looking at the file with PDFDebugger (preferable, the 2.0 version, which is much better). I'm afraid it is not easy.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I have checked in Adobe Acrobat to create such image field, but there is not such option. We cannot have any control type called image field, images are added directly in PDF but cannot be included as a part of acroform.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I have found that PDSignatureField is a kind of field which can embed image in form of field. Is it possible to create such custom PDField class with the help of PDSignatureField class i.e., by looking into its souce code and create custome image field class which extends PDField. Is this feasible option? I doubt that creating such custom field will help us because in PDFBox there are only four field types - Text, Checkbox, Button and Signature. For other types, PDFBox might not set COSDictionary objects or might throw exception. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: In theory, it should be possible with ordinary fields, because "appearance streams" (which are "what you see") are "Form XObjects", and these have a content stream and resources just like a PDF page. But I have never tested this. Problem is that this would be hours, maybe days of work (and pain) to create all this, so no help from me :-(
Re your second remark: my thought was about ordinary fields. The visual signatures is an even more complicated mess :-(

Comment: And to make things even more confusing: the term "Form XObjects" has nothing to do with Acroform. These are just content streams (= sequence of PDF operators with their parameters) with resources that can be invoked from a page content stream, or are used as appearance streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed above issue to treat an image as the field.

I have taken PDPushButton field and set image in it, so that I can show/hide an image through java script too.

Look at below sample code:

```
package sample.pdfbox.example;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSFloat;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDPushButton;

public class MyPushButton2 
{
    public static void main(String arg[])  throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDResources res = new PDResources();
        String fontName = res.addFont(font);
        String da = "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g";

        COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary(); 
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.FIELDS, new COSArray());
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString(da));

        PDAcroForm acroForm =  new PDAcroForm(document, acroFormDict);
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);


        float x = 10f;
        float y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();  
        float yOffset = 15f;
        float yCurrent = y - yOffset;  

     // Create appearance stream for local image
        COSArray rectStream = new COSArray();
        rectStream.add(new COSFloat(0));
        rectStream.add(new COSFloat(0));
        rectStream.add(new COSFloat(25));
        rectStream.add(new COSFloat(25));

        final PDRectangle boundingBox = new PDRectangle(rectStream);
        InputStream imageStream = MyPushButton2.class.getResourceAsStream("/Penguins.jpg");
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
        PDXObjectImage image = new PDPixelMap(document,bImage);

        PDResources holderFormResources = new PDResources();
        PDStream holderFormStream = new PDStream(document);
        PDXObjectForm holderForm = new PDXObjectForm(holderFormStream);
        holderForm.setResources(holderFormResources);
        holderForm.setBBox(boundingBox);
        holderForm.setFormType(1);

        PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
        PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(holderForm.getCOSStream());
        appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);

        PDResources innerFormResources = new PDResources();
        PDStream innerFormStream = new PDStream(document);
        PDXObjectForm innerForm = new PDXObjectForm(innerFormStream);
        innerForm.setResources(innerFormResources);
        innerForm.setBBox(boundingBox);
        innerForm.setFormType(1);

        String innerFormName = holderFormResources.addXObject(innerForm, "FRM");

        PDResources imageFormResources = new PDResources();
        PDStream imageFormStream = new PDStream(document);

        PDXObjectForm imageForm = new PDXObjectForm(imageFormStream);
        imageForm.setResources(imageFormResources);
        imageForm.setBBox(boundingBox);
        imageForm.setFormType(1);

        String imageFormName = innerFormResources.addXObject(imageForm, "n");
        String imageName = imageFormResources.addXObject(image, "img");

        String holderFormComment = "q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /" + innerFormName + " Do Q \n";
        String innerFormComment = "q q 5 0 0 5 0 0 cm /" + imageFormName + " Do Q\n";
        String imgFormComment = "q 5 0 0 5 0 0 cm /" + imageName + " Do Q\n";

        appendRawCommands(holderFormStream.createOutputStream(), holderFormComment);
        appendRawCommands(innerFormStream.createOutputStream(), innerFormComment);
        appendRawCommands(imageFormStream.createOutputStream(), imgFormComment);

        // Create Pushbutton containing status image
        COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray rect = new COSArray();
        rect.add(new COSFloat(100));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(500));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(300));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(700));

        cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field Type
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("ImageField1"));
        cosDict.setInt(COSName.F, 4);
        cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 65536);

        PDPushButton button = new PDPushButton(document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(), cosDict);
        button.setReadonly(true);

        button.getWidget().setAppearance(appearance);
        page.getAnnotations().add(button.getWidget());                          
        acroForm.getFields().add(button); // Added this line for Tilman's comment

        yCurrent = yCurrent - 20 - yOffset;

        File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\ImageButton.pdf");
        System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        document.save(file);
        document.close();
    }

    public static void appendRawCommands(OutputStream os, String commands) throws IOException {
        os.write(commands.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this solution helps!!